# com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I currently receive a lot of crash reports from Android device. Check out the error message below. I am using expo sdk 49 and react native 0.72.5.

I am not 100% sure if this is the reason. But the crash happened after I implemented Expo watchPositionAsync to get location and background task to refresh token. It works like a charm locally, but not in production. Even I set up Sentry, but it's reporting everything but this.

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

```
Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException:
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:65)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
  at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

I tried to install Sentry and reproduce it in local